# When added HTML Form tag JavaScript executes, but magically disappeared

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, execution

I had a successful execution before adding the form tag. But somehow the JavaScript is replaced. Is there a way to do without this form submission. I need to pass the data to PHP. Thank You in Advance..

This is the **html** I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
    <script src="riu003.js"></script> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="/riu/riu-01/riu001.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <div id="aaa"> 
        </div> 
        <button style="width: 100%" class="bbb" onclick="addfielderbutt()">Add Fields</button> 
        <button style="width: 100%; height: 45px; background-color: dodgerblue" onclick="submity()" type="Submit" value="submit">SUBMIT</button> 
    </form> 
</body> 

</html>
```

And here is the **JavaScript** file.

```
function createElemented(element, attribute, inner) {
    if (typeof(element) === "undefined") { return false; }
    if (typeof(inner) === "undefined") { inner = ""; }
    var el = document.createElement(element);
    if (typeof(attribute) === 'object') {
        for (var key in attribute) {
            el.setAttribute(key, attribute[key]);
        }
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(inner)) { inner = [inner]; }
    for (var k = 0; k < inner.length; k++) {
        if (inner[k].tagName) {
            el.appendChild(inner[k]);
        } else {
            el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inner[k]));
        }
    }
    return el;
};
var noofclicks = 0;

function addfielderbutt() {
    noofclicks = noofclicks + 1;
    var uptexty = createElemented("TEXTAREA", { class: "upt_" + noofclicks, name: "positiveuse_" + noofclicks, type: "text" }, "Type the postive uses here...");
    var nptexty = createElemented("TEXTAREA", { class: "unt_" + noofclicks, name: "negativeuse_" + noofclicks, type: "text" }, "Type the negative uses here...");
    var dptexty = createElemented("TEXTAREA", { class: "dpt_" + noofclicks, name: "positivedisuse_" + noofclicks, type: "text" }, "Type the postive disuses here...");
    var dntexty = createElemented("TEXTAREA", { class: "dnt_" + noofclicks, name: "negativedisuse_" + noofclicks, type: "text" }, "Type the negative disuses here...");
    var breakkk = createElemented("BR");
    document.getElementById("aaa").appendChild(uptexty);
    document.getElementById("aaa").appendChild(nptexty);
    document.getElementById("aaa").appendChild(dptexty);
    document.getElementById("aaa").appendChild(dntexty);
    document.getElementById("aaa").appendChild(breakkk);
}

function submity(){  
    document.cookie = "numberofclicks="+noofclicks; 
}
```

Comment: Please format your source code properly and please add the source code for your `submity()` function. I believe this could be the problem. Also if you want to submit data to a server without redirecting/moving the client the post location you can use `ajax` which I recommend you research as this might be of some good use to you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because your submit button have `type="submit"`. Since you mentioned it was working before adding the form tag, i'm guessing that `submity()` is the function that sends the data to PHP, but now that you added a form tag, it will not be executed. This is because a clicking a button with `type="submit"` inside a form tag not only sends the form data to the link in the action attribute, but also navigates to it.

Comment: I tried with the input tag but it still doesn't give any response while clicking the Add Fields button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure I understand the issue with your original code - that being the inability to prevent the default action occurring when using the button. I modified the code a little and added the ajax function which would allow the sending of the form data without reloading the page. Essentially the same code but rewritten to use external event listeners rather than inline event handler calls. Hope i helps.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* 

            this is to emulate whatever code you have in 
            the form action /riu/riu-01/riu001.php

        */
        exit( json_encode( $_POST ) );
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>You have got to have a title...</title>
    <style>
        button{ width: 100%;height:45px;background-color: dodgerblue }
        .bbb{}
        fieldset{border:none;}
    </style>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
            /*
                presumably this will be in riu003.js
                ------------------------------------
            */

            let counter = 0; // the counter to be incremented.
            let url=location.href; // change this to "/riu/riu-01/riu001.php"




            const submity=function(e){
                /*
                    explicitly prevent the default form submission
                */
                e.preventDefault();

                /* The payload is a FormData object */
                let payload=new FormData( document.querySelector('form[name="myform"]') );
                /*
                    The callback can do far more than this...
                */
                let callback=function( r ){
                    alert( r )
                }
                /*
                    send the ajax request to the backend PHP script.
                    The actual url used will not be `location.href`
                    according to the original code...
                */
                ajax.call( this, url, payload, callback );
            };


            /* a variation on the createElemented function */
            const create=function(type,attributes,parent){
                try{
                    let el = ( typeof( type )=='undefined' || type==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( type );
                    let _arr=['innerhtml','innertext','html','text'];
                    for( let x in attributes ) if( attributes.hasOwnProperty( x ) && !~_arr.indexOf( x ) ) el.setAttribute( x, attributes[ x ] );
                    if( attributes.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') || attributes.hasOwnProperty('html') ) el.innerHTML=attributes.innerHTML || attributes.html;
                    if( attributes.hasOwnProperty('innerText') || attributes.hasOwnProperty('text') ) el.innerText=attributes.innerText || attributes.text;
                    if( parent!=null ) typeof( parent )=='object' ? parent.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( parent ).appendChild( el );
                    return el;
                }catch( err ){
                    console.warn( err.message );
                }
            };

            /* ultra basic ajax function to send a POST request */
            const ajax=function(url,payload,callback){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response );
                    }
                    xhr.open('POST',url,true);
                    xhr.send(payload);
            };

            const addfielderbutt=function(e){
                counter++;

                /* explicitly prevent the default action being triggered */
                e.preventDefault();

                /* create a fieldset and append new children to it */
                let fieldset=create( 'fieldset', {}, document.getElementById('aaa') );

                /* add the children */
                create( 'textarea',{ 'class':'upt_' + counter, name:'positiveuse_' + counter },fieldset );
                create( 'textarea',{ 'class':'unt_' + counter, name:'negativeuse_' + counter },fieldset );
                create( 'textarea',{ 'class':'dpt_' + counter, name:'positivedisuse_' + counter },fieldset );
                create( 'textarea',{ 'class':'dnt_' + counter, name:'negativedisuse_' + counter },fieldset );
            };

            /*
                Bind the event handlers to the buttons
            */
            document.querySelector( 'button.bbb' ).addEventListener( 'click', addfielderbutt );
            document.querySelector( 'button[ type="submit" ]' ).addEventListener( 'click', submity );
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body> 
        <form name='myform' method='post'> 
            <div id='aaa'>
                <!-- generated content will appear here -->
            </div>

            <button class='bbb'>Add Fields</button> 
            <button type='Submit' value='submit'>SUBMIT</button> 
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to use Ajax. Can't it be done without the use of Ajax.
I just want to get the Textbox to get displayed, but somehow it gets submitted without any client side response I guess. Could you explain why this happens.
And do I really need Ajax to display the textboxes.

Comment: certainly it can. The ajax only sends the information - it can use a standard submit method. I was just unsure because of the assigned event handler to the submit button - seems redundant unless `submity` does some fancy stuff unknown to us